# CloudFormation Stack Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template like this, to create a role to launch EKS

```html
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'moba production'

Parameters:
  EKSIAMRoleName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the IAM role for the EKS service to assume.
Resources:
  EKSIAMRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - eks.amazonaws.com
        Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      RoleName: !Ref EKSIAMRoleName
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy
Outputs:
  EKSIAMRole:
    Description: EKSIAMRole
    Value: !Ref EKSIAMRole
```

But I got this message [Missing required field Principal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBf99.png), please help to clue to fix it, thanks

> Missing required field Principal (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: af18b2eb-06b0-474e-82bc-b80505f544fd; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **incorrect indentation**. It should be:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'moba production'

Parameters:
  EKSIAMRoleName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the IAM role for the EKS service to assume.
Resources:
  EKSIAMRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
                Service:
                    - eks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
            - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      RoleName: !Ref EKSIAMRoleName
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy
Outputs:
  EKSIAMRole:
    Description: EKSIAMRole
    Value: !Ref EKSIAMRole
```

Comment: thank you Marcin, is there any tool to validate such kind of issue, it is quite "hard to fix" to someone new ?

Comment: @LuongTo There is [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint), but I don't know if it would pickup your particular issue or not. There is also AWS CLI [validate-template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html).